# AUIScript Val().length is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay-aui

I have a email address field and 3 radio buttons. You must click one radio button and it will redirect you to another page. I am testing here If I can get the value of radio button (Category.val).

Here is my code:

```
   <aui:script>
    AUI().use(
      'aui-modal','liferay-portlet-url','aui-io-request','aui-base',
      function(A) {
        $('a.btn-resetpass').click(function() {
            var validator = $(".pwdLength"),
                Category = $(".1");

            if (validator.val().length != 0) {
                 alert(Category.val()); 
                if (Category.val() == 1) {

                }
                else if (Category.val() == 2) {

                }
                else if (Category.val() == 3) {

                }
                //$('.resetForm').submit();
            }
            else {
                alert ("Please input a valid email");
            }
            $('.resetForm').submit();
        });
    });
    </aui:script>
```

Please help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: the problem is `$(".1")`... can you share the html for the radio buttons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the selector used for radio buttons. You are trying to get all elements with class `1`, but if what you need is the selected radio so you have to use `.1:checked`.

Without the html it is difficult to form a proper selector, but assuming those are the only radio buttons in the page you can try

```
Category = $("input:radio:checked");
```

**Update:**
As per your update the class used by you is `radioB` so

```
Category = $(".radioB:checked");//no need to use `[type=radio]` if the class is only assigned to the radio elements
```

Comment: **Category = $(".radioB[type=radio]:checked");**

Thank you very much @Arun P Johny

Comment: @ひかり no need to use `[type=radio]` if the class is only assigned to the radio elements so `Category = $(".radioB:checked");` else use `$(".radioB[type=radio]:checked");`

Comment: I've tried that but still i got undefined. but when I tried this **Category = $(".radioB[type=radio]:checked");** it's now working like charm. But anyway THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your Quick Response! thank you @Arun.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used:

**Category = $(".radioB[type=radio]:checked");**

Thanks for the help of @Arun P Johny. Thank you very much.